# use zeromq inside an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, zeromq

I am trying to use zeromq inside an eclipse plugin. 
The OSGi framework denies the use of normal external jars; thus, the solution is to bundle them into plugins themselves. Following a simple process (described also in 
http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJarToPlugin/article.html), I managed to use some of the external jars I needed without any suffering.

However, when I tried to bundle the jzmq.jar, I am having issues. The 'zmq plugin' is created easily but, once it is used, it freezes by looping into org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop.

Anyone of you ever used zeromq inside an eclipse plugin successfully? 
Any hint on how to solve this issue?